# Extension/Optimisation of code: from one to several iterations

Tags: r

For a matrix of pairwise distances `pdm` (symmetric), where each row/column represents a point, and a vector of distances `r`, I will do th following for each point

```r
# some small toy data 
# note. real data is bigger, e.g. ~15k points.
pdm <- matrix(data = c(0, 4, 3,
                       4, 0, 2, 
                       3, 2, 0), 
              nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
r <- seq(0, 5, .5)
length(r)
#> [1] 11

# index m correspondens to order of points. 
m <- c(1, 2, 3)

# change format 
pdml <- as.list(as.data.frame(pdm))

# ---- 1
# procedure for first point (1) 
a <- list()
for(i in seq_along(r)) {
  a[[i]] <- ifelse(0 < pdml[[1]] & pdml[[1]] <= r[i], 1, 0) 
  a[[i]] <- which(a[[i]] != 0)
  # if-statement is needed since which() produces annoying integer(0) entries
  if(identical(a[[i]], integer(0))) a[[i]] <- 0
  a[[i]] <- sum(m[1] * m[a[[i]]])
}

# change format 
do.call(rbind, a)
#>       [,1]
#>  [1,]    0
#>  [2,]    0
#>  [3,]    0
#>  [4,]    0
#>  [5,]    0
#>  [6,]    0
#>  [7,]    3
#>  [8,]    3
#>  [9,]    5
#> [10,]    5
#> [11,]    5

# ---- 2 
# procedure for second point (2), 
# ... adaption: pdml[[2]] and m[2]
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**Desired Output**
After the calculation is done, I would like to calc. the average for each distance $r_i$ across all points.

Can somebody please provide a solution to extend my approach to all points or by showing an alternative, which cerntainly is more efficient? Also, any recommendation on how to improve my question is much appreciated.

---

Note, if it makes things easier, it is, of course, also an option to  use the upper/lower half of `pdm` only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you precalculate the possible products you want to sum with `tcrossprod(m)`,
you can simplify the calculation to a couple of matrix operations:

```r
# Input data
m <- c(1, 2, 3)
d <- matrix(
  data = c(
    0, 4, 3,
    4, 0, 2,
    3, 2, 0
  ),
  nrow = 3,
  ncol = 3
)

r <- seq(0, 5) # Reduced for simplicity

# Possible summands
v <- tcrossprod(m) * (d != 0)
v
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    0    2    3
#> [2,]    2    0    6
#> [3,]    3    6    0

# The calculation
a <- sapply(r, \(r) colSums(v * (d <= r)))
a
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#> [1,]    0    0    0    3    5    5
#> [2,]    0    0    6    6    8    8
#> [3,]    0    0    6    9    9    9
```

And since you said you then wanted the mean for each distance, over points:

```r
colMeans(a)
#> [1] 0.000000 0.000000 4.000000 6.000000 7.333333 7.333333
```

A slightly more obscure but potentially faster way to find `a` would be
with 3-d arrays:

```r
colSums(outer(v, rep(1, length(r))) * outer(d, r, `<=`))
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#> [1,]    0    0    0    3    5    5
#> [2,]    0    0    6    6    8    8
#> [3,]    0    0    6    9    9    9
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Whenever I start to write for loops I know that I am loosing track, but finding and integrating vectorised functions according to my needs is hard for me.